# JS: Handle with find() property undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, find, ecmascript-2017

I have a method which returns a value from an element in the array. Not all the elements have the property I want to return. I would like to do this function with one line using the method `find()`. I've tried this way to solve it:

```
getExecsFromTour(tourId){
 return this.repInfo.find(el => el.id == tourId ).execs || [];
}
```

But the elements which don't contain the property `execs` return an error of `undefined`.

To solve it, I had to store the result in a local variable:

```
getExecsFromTour(tourId){
    let items       = this.repInfo.find(el => el.id == tourId);
    return items    != undefined ? items.execs : [];
}
```

But I would like to know if I am missing something and this function can be achieved with one sentence.

Comment: If you really need this to be one line, you can use `(this.repInfo.find(el => el.id == tourId) || {}).execs || [];`

Comment: There is no harm in making things readable on multiple lines....

Comment: Hello! Thanks @Titus, I totally forgot the `{}`statment >.<. @epascarello You're right, but I was curious about how to solve this, because it might help me in the future!

Answer (score 13):

You seem to have the general idea, `Array.prototype.find` will search the array for the first element which, when used as an argument of the callback, will have the callback return a truthy value. If nothing is found, it returns `undefined`.

Your code should work, but yes, one way to do it in one line (if you want) is to use:

```
getExecsFromTour(tourId){
  return (this.repInfo.find(el => el.id == tourId) || {}).execs || [];
}
```

If `Array.prototype.find` returns `undefined`, the first inner parenthetical expression will be evaluated to empty object, which can attempt (and fail) to access the `.execs` key without a `TypeError`, which will also evaluate to `undefined`, in which case the function returns empty array, which is what your code above does.

EDIT: Someone commented this solution already, lol, but as the comments say, nothing wrong with keeping it multiline (more readable that way).

Comment: Hello! Yes, somebody before answer this, but none with your explication. Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

what about

```
getExecsFromTour(tourId){
     return this.repInfo.find(el => 'execs' in el && el.id == tourId ).execs || [];
}
```

...

EDITED

```
var a = [{execs : 1, id:4}, {id:5}];
function getExecsFromTour(tourId, x){
    return (x = a.find(el => 'execs' in el && el.id == tourId )) ? x.execs : [];
}
```

this time at least I ran it couple of times

Comment: No downvote from me, but I can give you another one if you want.

Comment: The answer is wrong.... `[{id:'foo', execs:[]}].find(el => 'execs' in el && el.id == 'bar' ).execs` It still going to throw the same error.