# Array.Find failing if not finding string in Array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm using an array.find below and it works to return BreakdownPalletID when the itemScan value is found in the array. If it's not found my application returns a
'Cannot read property breakdownPalletID of undefined'. The user enters the itemScan so I want to have this behavoir and then to signify to the user that that string was not found. How can I handle this undefined error?

```
 let palletID = this.transferPalletBreakdownData.Sku.find(x => x.sku == this.itemScan).breakdownPalletID
      console.log(palletID);
```

Comment: Why not check if the value returned from `find()` is `undefined` before trying to access the property?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JS: Handle with find() property undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52389757/js-handle-with-find-property-undefined)

Comment: `(this.transfer.Sku.find(x => x.sku == this.itemScan) || {}).breakdownPalletID`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array.prototype.find()` method will return null if an item does not exist else it will return the expected item. So just add `null` checks it's enough to get rid of the error.

```
 const itemFound = this.transferPalletBreakdownData.Sku.find(x => x.sku == this.itemScan)


let palletID = itemFound && itemFound.breakdownPalletID
console.log(palletID);
```

You want more than one item based on criteria matched then we need to used `filter` instead of a `find().`

```
const matches = this.transferPalletBreakdownData.Sku.filter(x => x.sku == this.itemScan)

const items = matches.map(item => itemFound.breakdownPalletID)

console.log(items)
```

Comment: awesome this looks to  have worked... do you know how to have the find function return multiple results if it finds multiple matches?

Comment: Array.prototype.find() will return only one item(first match), I guess you are expecting filter(), can you please try with filter function.

Comment: I was able to filter the array just to the items I wanted to see... this seems to be working great..... I'm using this so the user can filter an array to only see items he 'searches' for.... once I accomplish this how can I 'unfilter' the array if the user selects something along the lines of a 'clear filters' button and then show the entire array again?

Answer (score 1):

Use a logical OR operator `||`:

```
let palletID = (this.transferPalletBreakdownData.Sku.find(x => x.sku == this.itemScan) || {}).breakdownPalletID;
console.log(palletID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out the following code.

```
const sku = this.transferPalletBreakdownData.Sku.find(x => x.sku == this.itemScan);
if (sku) {
  console.log(sku.breakdownPalletID);
} else {
  console.log('No SKU');
}
```