# handle find property in array if undefined

Tags: javascript, find

I have this simple code that works. However it feels cheesy and like I am doing something stupid.
So is this how I would handle this if I wanted to be in one line?

```
    let lifeColors = [
        { lives: 1, color: 'lime' },
        { lives: 2, color: 'orange' },
        { lives: 3, color: 'salmon' },
    ]

    let lives = 20;

    let color = (lifeColors.find(x => x.lives === lives) || {color: 'white'}).color;
    console.log(color)
```

My inspiration was from this post

[JS: Handle with find() property undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52389757/js-handle-with-find-property-undefined)

Comment: Maybe `let color = (lifeColors.find(({lives}) => livez === lives))?.color || 'white';` is a bit less "_cheesy_" ..? Note, that I've changed the variable name `lives` to `livez` to prevent the outer variable shadowing inside the function.

Comment: hey thanks for the replay. However I get error "livez is not defined"

Comment: Please re-read my comment above. I said I changed the name of the __variable__ ...

Comment: Yup I made a mistake. Thanks a lot for this. Have a nice day!